# android automaticly pair bluetooth device with specific name

Tags: android, bluetooth, pairing

I am looking for a way to scan for all bluetooth devices with certain names (lets say "SC_0001", "SC_0002", e.t.c.) and automatically pair them with my phone.

i already created an app that can list all paired devices and let the user select one. but i dont want the user to have to pair all these devices manually (it whould take way too much time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getname()` method of the BluetoothDevice class
**According to the Documentation of getname()**

> Get the friendly Bluetooth name of the remote device.
>
> The local adapter will automatically retrieve remote names when performing a device scan, and will cache them. This method just returns the name for this device from the cache.

Then, compare both the strings using `str1.equals(str2)`method. 
**Edit 1**
Here is the way, you can get the list of unpaired devices.

```
                         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                         String action = intent.getAction();

                         // When discovery finds a device
                         if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                             // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                             BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                             // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                             if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) 
                             {
                                // compare device.getName() and your string here, if satisfied, add them to the list-view.
                                 tv.setText(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
```

Here is the link to documentation. [BluetoothDevices](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html)

Comment: yes i have worked with this class before, but only with paired devices. Can i also find unpaired devices, read their names and then pair the right ones?
(and if so, how di i pair them)

Comment: Yea, their is a way, I have edited the code. Have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this exactly what i need!